# Extracting timestamps from an XML file

Tags: c++, xml

I am supposed to extract timestamps from the following XML document and output the timestamps to an output file. However, what I've created so far extracts the timestamps in addition to the code before them, when I just want the timestamps(eg:timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:16.468Z" ) . Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

XML document: http://pastebin.com/DLVF0cXY

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string tempStr;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("Outputdata.txt");
inFile.open("Groupproject.xml");
if (inFile.fail()) {
    cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
while (inFile) {
    inFile >> tempStr;
    if (tempStr.find('Z\"') != string::npos) {
        cout << "Found timestamp" << tempStr;
        outFile << tempStr << endl;
        cout << "Copied to file" << endl;
    }
}
inFile.close();
outFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `getline()` to read one line at time? ... This would make what you are trying to do far more manageable.

Comment: If you are doing anything more than trivial processing I'd suggest a using an xml library.  How are you to know what timestamp belongs to what data item?

Comment: @NathanielBrough How would I ignore all the data before time timestamp(eg: timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:16.468Z" )  with `getline()` though? To me it looks like the issue of outputting gratuitous data before the timestamp would still exist.

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots You will have the same issue using getline it will simply speed up the process and reduce the time  it would take to copy accross the data from your filestream to the string. I am currently in the proccess of writing a full answer using string::find.

Comment: @AnonMail This is for a group project in an introductory C++ college class. No knowledge of XML is expected at all, so I don't know how to use an XML library. There must be a way to accomplish this only using methods a introductory C++ student with very limited knowledge of C++ would have knowledge of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anon Mail has suggested If you are trying to parse the entire `.xml` file with different parameters I would suggest using an xml library such as rapidxml or tinyxml. However for the purpose of the question I have included a version of your code that should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
using namespace std;
string tempStr;
// escaped double qoute.
string findStr = "timestamp=\""

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("Outputdata.txt");
inFile.open("Groupproject.xml");
if (inFile.fail()) {
    cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}

size_t found;

while (inFile) {
    getline(inFile,tempStr);
    found = tempStr.find(findStr);
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// Erases from beggining to end of timestamp="
tempStr.erase(tempStr.begin(),(found + tempStr.length()));

// Finds index of next double qoute.
found = tempStr.findStr("\"");

if (found=std::string::npos)
{
    cerr << "Could not find matching qoute:";
    exit(1);
}

// Erases from matching qoute to the end of the string.
tempStr.erase(found, tempStr.end());

cout << "timestamp found" << tempStr << "Saving to outFile" <<  endl;

outFile << tempStr;

inFile.close();
outFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I will have to look into XML libraries for future reference, as I'm sure they will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `std::string` you can use it's member functions to find an occurrence of a timestamp field.  Use `find` to get the beginning of the timestamp field and also to find the end.  And then use the `substr` function to extract the correct characters.